# How to fix overflowing text on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

### The Problem:

I am having an issue with my text spilling outside of my menu bar when I have my window resized. I know the device that I am on has a weird display size (galaxy z fold 3), but when I am on my small screen the text spills over and looks bad.

[image: Image of text overflowing]

Code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".menu").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".menu").removeClass("active");
      $(this).find("a").html("<ion-icon name='menu-outline'></ion-icon>");
    } else {
      $(".menu").addClass("active");
      $(this).find("a").html("<ion-icon name='close-outline'></ion-icon>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #0B3442;
}

.top-bar span {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.top-bar li {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.top-bar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-bar a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
}

nav {
  background: #537F3A;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #000
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #0B3442
}

.logo {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: left;
}

.logo a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.logo a:hover {
  color: #0B3442;
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-width: 680px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
  .menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu.active,
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  .services {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card {
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
}

.banner-card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.banner-card img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner-text h4 {
  font-size: xxx-large;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text p {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('background.jpg')
}

.banner-text button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0B3442;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}

.banner-text button:hover,
.banner-text button:focus,
.banner-text button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.title h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.title h1::after {
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.services {
  width: 85%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 75px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #0B3442;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .icon {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #537F3A;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #7a99b8;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #537F3A;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mountain Man Landscapes Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- This is the topbar that hosts all the social links and phone number -->

  <div class="top-bar">
    <span><a href="tel:555555555"><ion-icon name="call-outline"></ion-icon> (555) 555-5555</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation bar -->

  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo">Mountain Man Landscapes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <a href="#">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- This is the navbar resizing hamburger script -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Banner card that has the welcome image and text aswell as the gallery button -->

  <div class="banner-card">
    <div class="banner-text">
      <h4>We don't beat around the bush.</h4>
      <p>Landscapes has all the professional skills required to make your ideas come to life. With over 10 plus years of experience there is nothing our experts can't handle.</p>
      <button onclick="#">View Gallery</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Services section hosts the services cards -->

  <div class="section">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Our Services</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-ruler"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Design</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Build</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-scissors"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Maintain</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to get the text to resize properly within the navbar so it looks appealing. Not sure really what I should do. I am relatively new to HTML and I appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Can you mockup what you want it to look like?

Comment: Apparently, there is not enough space to display both the logo and the text. We are happy to help you changing the code to achieve the desired result, however Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask for UI/UX advice. Please add a specific desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a media query to change the font-size property of your text ?
Also, for mobile devices, it is recommended to not "force" à content to fit on an horizontal axis if the result is a super small text difficult to read. I would recommend displaying your text under your logo on mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Added some css at the bottom marked `/* new */`:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".toggle").on("click", function() {
    if ($(".menu").hasClass("active")) {
      $(".menu").removeClass("active");
      $(this).find("a").html("<ion-icon name='menu-outline'></ion-icon>");
    } else {
      $(".menu").addClass("active");
      $(this).find("a").html("<ion-icon name='close-outline'></ion-icon>");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

a,
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.top-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  background: #0B3442;
}

.top-bar span {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-bar ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.top-bar li {
  margin: 0px 5px;
}

.top-bar a {
  color: #fff;
}

.top-bar a:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 174, 255);
}

nav {
  background: #537F3A;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  color: #000
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #0B3442
}

.logo {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: left;
}

.logo a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow-wrap: normal;
}

.logo a:hover {
  color: #0B3442;
}

.logo img {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.toggle {
  font-size: 30px;
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-width: 680px) {
  nav {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px 20px;
  }
  .menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: none;
  }
  .menu.active,
  .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .toggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  .services {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .card {
    width: 85%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 20px 0px;
  }
}

.banner-card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.banner-card img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.banner-text h4 {
  font-size: xxx-large;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text p {
  font-size: large;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('background.jpg')
}

.banner-text button {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0B3442;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
  transition-property: box-shadow, transform;
}

.banner-text button:hover,
.banner-text button:focus,
.banner-text button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.title h1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 42px;
}

.title h1::after {
  content: "";
  height: 4px;
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

.services {
  width: 85%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 75px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20px 20px;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background-color: #0B3442;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.card .icon {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #537F3A;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.card p {
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}

.card:hover {
  background-color: #7a99b8;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.button {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: #537F3A;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
}

/* new */

body{
  min-width: 320px;
}

@media (max-width: 680px) {
  .logo {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
  .logo a {
    font-size:16px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mountain Man Landscapes Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- This is the topbar that hosts all the social links and phone number -->

  <div class="top-bar">
    <span><a href="tel:555555555"><ion-icon name="call-outline"></ion-icon> (555) 555-5555</a></span>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <ion-icon name="logo-instagram"></ion-icon>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- Navigation bar -->

  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="logo.png" alt="logo">Mountain Man Landscapes</a>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle">
      <a href="#">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Solutions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- This is the navbar resizing hamburger script -->

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Banner card that has the welcome image and text aswell as the gallery button -->

  <div class="banner-card">
    <div class="banner-text">
      <h4>We don't beat around the bush.</h4>
      <p>Landscapes has all the professional skills required to make your ideas come to life. With over 10 plus years of experience there is nothing our experts can't handle.</p>
      <button onclick="#">View Gallery</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Services section hosts the services cards -->

  <div class="section">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Our Services</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="services">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-ruler"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Design</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-screwdriver-wrench"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Build</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-scissors"></i>
        </div>
        <h2>Maintain</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum dolore recusandae i</p>
        <a href="" class="button">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```